# 一度表示されたESLintのErrorがバグ修正後も表示され続ける（Nuxt.js）

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, axios, eslint

一度表示されたESLintのErrorが、バグ修正後も表示され続けてしまいます。
バグ修正後に.eslintcacheファイルを削除して、アプリケーションを再起動するとエラーは表示されなくなります。
キャッシュファイルを削除せずとも、修正後はエラーが更新されるようにしたいです。

#### 詳細

create-nuxt-appでアプリケーション作成後、index.vueを以下のように作成しました。
（意図的にエラーを出すようにしています。）

- index.vue（修正前）

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>
<script>
// const hello = 'hello'
alert(hello)
</script>
```

エラーが表示されることを確認したのち、hello変数宣言のコメントを解除しました。

- index.vue（修正後）

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>
<script>
const hello = 'hello'
alert(hello)
</script>
```

しかし、リビルド（自動）後もエラーが消えません。
alertは正常に実行されました。

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

```
nuxt_1  |  ERROR  ESLintError
nuxt_1  | /app/pages/index.vue
nuxt_1  |   88:7  error  'hello' is not defined  no-undef
```

そこで、次のことを試しました。

- アプリケーションの再起動 => エラーは表示されたままでした。
- .eslintcacheファイルを削除して、リビルド => エラーは表示されたままでした。
- .eslintcacheファイルを削除して、アプリケーションを再起動 => エラーは消えました。

キャッシュが原因なのは間違い無いと思いますが、何故ESLintがindex.vueの変更を検知してくれないのかがわかりません。

#### 環境

MacOS Big Sur 11.1

開発環境はDockerで作成しています。

```
# docker -v
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61
```

- Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.4-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git && \
    npm install -g npm && \
    npm install -g @vue/cli@4.3.0 && \
    npm install -g create-nuxt-app
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./nuxt
    tty: true
    command: yarn dev
    volumes:
      - ./nuxt/app:/app:delegated
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

(:delegateを外しても結果は同じでした。）
以下がライブラリのバージョンです。

```
# npm list --depth=0
+-- @nuxtjs/axios@5.12.5
+-- @nuxtjs/eslint-config@5.0.0
+-- @nuxtjs/eslint-module@3.0.2
+-- @nuxtjs/pwa@3.3.4
+-- @nuxtjs/vuetify@1.11.3
+-- babel-eslint@10.1.0
+-- core-js@3.8.3
+-- eslint@7.18.0
+-- eslint-config-prettier@7.2.0
+-- eslint-plugin-nuxt@2.0.0
+-- eslint-plugin-prettier@3.3.1
+-- eslint-plugin-vue@7.5.0
+-- husky@4.3.8
+-- lint-staged@10.5.3
+-- nuxt@2.14.12
`-- prettier@2.2.1
```

以上です。
お手数おかけしますが、ご教授をお願いいたします。

Comment: 修正前のエラーは何でしょうか？修正後のコードはそもそも文法が間違っているので `not defined` は当然の結果となります。

Comment: 伝わりづらかったようで、申し訳ありません。
最初に記載しているindex.vueが修正前のコードです。意図的にエラーを出しています。
これを修正してもエラーが消えないという問題です。
修正後のコードは載せていませんが、index.vueのコメントを解除したものです。

Comment: そのあたりが明確になるように本文を修正しました。
よろしくお願いします。